# How to get Xdebug to connect when webhook call arrives via ngrok on MacOS

Tags: php, macos, apache, xdebug, ngrok

I currently run Apache 2.4, PHP 7.2, and Xdebug 2.9 on MacOS 10.14.6

Presently I can only use Xdebug when I enter a URL into the browser running on my mac that is handled by Apache running on same.

I'd like to be able to use Xdebug to single-step through PHP code when a webhook call arrives at my Mac via ngrok tunnel and is handled by Apache.

I've researched a bit and haven't found anything specific that shows what is required to do this. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can configure Xdebug to always attempt to make a debugging session, instead of relying on the browser GET/POST/COOKIE arguments.

You must set `xdebug.remote_autostart` to `yes`: https://2.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_autostart

You also need to set `xdebug.remote_host` to the IP address of the machine where your IDE is running at (likely, the same one as where ngrok is running at, which I'm going to **guess**, is just localhost). So set: `xdebug.remote_host=localhost`.

Please be aware that Xdebug 2 is no longer supported, and you're encouraged to upgrade to Xdebug 3 instead. There the configuration names would be `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` and `xdebug.client_host=localhost` instead (See the [Upgrade Guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide)).

Xdebug 3 also has a new `xdebug_info()` function that can tell you how it is configured, and what it attempted to connect to, if at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response Derick. I will set remote_autostart and see if that works. I realize Xdebug 3 is now current but need to keep my old environment in place for a while. Will upgrade when possible.